# It's hard to listen to contractions or short forms

Tags: listening

I'm trying to enhance my English listening, but I'm facing an issue. It's hard to understand the short forms like *I'd*, *it's*, and *I've*. I always hear these short forms as one sound, and in any of the few cases where I can catch them, I'm confused. For example, when someone says "I'd", dose he mean "I had" or "i would"? The entire sentence drops from my understanding. How can I develop my English listening?

Comment: When you get more accustomed to English you will be able to understand phrases and sentences with these contractions even if you hear them all the same (e.g. as just "*I*"). You will be able to understand which was said by the context - what the overall phrase or sentence means, even when you cannot distinguish them by sound. Perhaps someone at ELL can offer help in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

"I'd" can mean either "I would" or "I had".

I and, I assume, most English speakers, interpret it somewhat unconsciously. After briefly pondering it, I've come up with two instances where the tense of the next verb indicates which "I'd" it is.

> I'd be

This is always "I would be".

> I'd been

This is always "I had been".

> I'd have

This is always "i would have". "Had" is the past tense of "have" so "I had have" doesn't really make sense.

Comically, people do often say "I'd had" which means "I had had".

"I'd had too much to drink" means I had had too much to drink, and

I'd never really thought about it, but I believe it basically works like this: the first had indicates the time, and the second one indicates possession. "I'd been walking" doesn't mean that the act of walking belonged to you, it means "Previously I engaged in walking", and "I had had a dog" means previously you had owned a dog.

One good way to look at it is to compare these two sentences:

> 1. I'd have a good time

and

> 2. I'd had a good time

The first sentence is "I would have a good time". The second sentence is "I had had a good time."

The first "had" in sentence 2 is the past tense of "would", the second "had" in sentence 2 is the past tense of "have". Here they are conveniently juxtaposed.

As far as I can tell, you can always replace "I'd had" with "I had" without actually changing the meaning, but I feel very uneasy saying that. If nothing else, I definitely want to say that there is something I can't put my finger on that I like about "i'd had".

Here's another interesting thing: "I had too much to drink", when heard out of context, can be misinterpreted as saying, in so many words, that you are drunk at the present moment. "I'd had too much to drink" is never used to communicate that you are currently drunk. You may be currently drunk, from that same excursion, but if you wanted to convey that to someone you would never say "I'd had too much to drink".

By the way, I'm no expert in this stuff. I do know that people will understand you if you use the words the way I described, but it's possible that there are some technical mistakes in there.